# Invalid number of arguments to Solidity at InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs

Tags: solidity

I made a simple contract for the testing purpose.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.18;
contract LocalEthereum {
    address public owner;
    function LocalEthereum() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        require(msg.sender == owner);
        _;
    }
    function setOwner(address _newOwner) onlyOwner external {
        owner = _newOwner;
    }
}
```

In the js application side,

```
  setOwner(account){
    contract.deployed().then(function(instance) {
      var instance = instance;
      return instance.setOwner( {from: account});
    }).then(function(txResult) {
       console.log('setowner',txResult)
    }).catch(function(e) {
      console.log(e);
    })
  }
```

running the js throws a exception, 
`Invalid number of arguments to Solidity function at Object.InvalidNumberOfSolidityArgs`

I can not figure out how such exception occurs? 
a second question, for the initialization code as shown below

```
    function LocalEthereum() public {
        owner = msg.sender;
    }
```

when does it come to execute?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you are not passing an argument to `instance.setOwner()` (the JS object is not the Solidity argument). It should look something like `instance.setOwner(account, {from: account})`. For your second question - the constructor runs when the contract is deployed, and only then.

Comment: Great. I've promoted this to an answer for the benefit of others. It would be helpful if you can mark it accepted if it resolves your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are not passing an argument to `instance.setOwner()`. (The JS object `{from: account}` is for the benefit of Web3 and is not the Solidity function argument.)

It ought to look something like `instance.setOwner(account, {from: account})`.

For your second question - the constructor runs when the contract is deployed, and only then.